# (Done) Req to reopen "Coworker wrote me into fictional book"

Tags: discussion, reopen-request

[Coworker wrote me into fictional book](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/179582/coworker-wrote-me-into-fictional-book)

Definitely work place related, clearly answerable, three votes to reopen already, Please can we have two more?

Comment: I am glad this question is reopened. I thought it should never have been closed. The fact that they work together certainly makes the situation different.

Answer (score 7):

While I think it would benefit from a more explicitly stated end goal I have to agree it's on-topic and answerable in it's current form.

I would have been hesitant to hammer it open unilaterally but it was at 4 Reopen votes when I looked so I've cast the fifth.

Comment: I sort of wish mods could have the ability to vote as a regular user in situations such as this. (Obviously while retaining the ability to "hammer it open" as required)

Comment: @GregoryCurrie yeah I suppose a sort of "light tap" with the hammer instead of a full swing would probably be useful at times.

Comment: @GregoryCurrie It's annoying in cases where as a user you want to vote a certain way that you wouldn't want to as a moderator, but thankfully it doesn't come up that often. What I usually do in that case is just ping my fellow mods or ask on chat. If 2-3 mods agree it's fine that's usually sufficient justification to sledgehammer it open. ;)